# GoogleService failed to initialize, but all settings is correct

Tags: android

I add firebase to my app and in logs I see this:

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource:
'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json 
or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

But I have `google-services.json` file in app/ directory, this is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}


android {
    ....  
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add google-service.json file. As I know you have created your app on google Developer from there you need to download the google-service.json file and put it into your app folder.

**Steps to solve this**

go to your application section in firebase

select setting icon on the left top side of the website.

in "general " tab of setting there is two part project and app.

go in app section and download "google_services.json"

and copy and place this file in app directory of the project.

and it will work now.